# Convert Python dictionary to Unicode for URL Request

Tags: python

I want to convert python dict to Unicode as given below .

input python dictionary =

```
{
     "getBalance": {
        "version": "1",
        "appID": "453733",
        "customerID": "453733",
        "AccountNumber": "000190600017042"
    }
  }
```

expected Output in Unicode =:

```
"{\n      \"getBalance\": {\n         \"version\": \"1\",\n         
 \"appID\": \"453733\",\n         \"customerID\": \"453733\",\n         
  \"AccountNumber\": \"000190600017042\"\n     \t }\n   \t}\n"
```

Comment: what have you tried? and is this really the best format to serialize this dictionary?

Comment: Why don't you just linearize it?

Comment: BTW that's not unicode @AkshayJadhao

Answer (score 1):

You can dump the data as a json and use it!

```
>>> import json
>>> dictionary = {
...      "getBalance": {
...         "version": "1",
...         "appID": "453733",
...         "customerID": "453733",
...         "AccountNumber": "000190600017042"
...     }
...   }
>>> dstr =json.dumps(dictionary)
>>> dstr
'{"getBalance": {"AccountNumber": "000190600017042", "version": "1", "customerID": "453733", "appID": "453733"}}'
```

And to load the data

```
>>> json.loads(dstr)
{u'getBalance': {u'appID': u'453733', u'version': u'1', u'customerID': u'453733', u'AccountNumber': u'000190600017042'}}
>>> type(json.loads(dstr))
<type 'dict'>
```

To have indents and escaping quotes, try dumping the data twice!

```
>>> json.dumps(dictionary)                            '{"getBalance": {"AccountNumber": "000190600017042", "version": "1", "customerID": "453733", "appID": "453733"}}'
>>> json.dumps(dictionary, indent=4)
'{\n    "getBalance": {\n        "AccountNumber": "000190600017042", \n        "version": "1", \n        "customerID": "453733", \n        "appID": "453733"\n    }\n}'
>>> print json.dumps(json.dumps(dictionary, indent=4))
"{\n    \"getBalance\": {\n        \"AccountNumber\": \"000190600017042\", \n        \"version\": \"1\", \n        \"customerID\": \"453733\", \n        \"appID\": \"453733\"\n    }\n}"
```

Comment: i have tried json.loads and json.dumps   but requests.request()  requires data in exacly same format as i have mentioned in expected output e.g.  "{\n      \"getBalance\": {\n         \"version\": \"1\",\n         
 \"appID\": \"453733\",\n         \"customerID\": \"453733\",\n         
  \"AccountNumber\": \"000190600017042\"\n     \t }\n   \t}\n"

Comment: If you are really concerned about the indents and escaping quotes, try dumping the data again! I've added the edits for the same

Answer (score 0):

Given your dictionary is stored in the `x` variable

```
uni = []
for e in str(x):
    if e == '\"':
       uni.append('\\')
       uni.append(e)
       continue

    if e == '{' or e == ',':
       uni.append(e)
       uni.append('\n')
       continue

    if e == '}':
       uni.append('\t')
       uni.append(e)
       uni.append('\n')
       continue

    uni.append(e)
```

This could work, but as suggested in comments, why don't you just linearize the dictionary and send it as-is?

Comment: sending direct dict as it is not works for me i need exact data as i mentioned in expected output